# Jquery pass parameter to called function

Tags: jquery, function

I want to pass this:

```
                $('.info-top').css({position:'absolute'});
```

to the called thumbHover function on the window resize. Can anyone show me how to do this?

```
 function thumbHover() {
            $('.thumb').hover(function () {
                    $('.info-top').text('Hover Text');
                },
                function () {
                    if (!$('.info-top').hasClass('active')) {
                        $('.info-top').text('');
                    }
                });
        }
        thumbHover();

        window.onresize = function () {
       thumbHover();
            if ($(".thumb").css("margin-bottom") === "1px") {
                $('.info-top').appendTo('#Grid');
            } else {
                $('.info-top').appendTo('#middle');
            }

    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `position` value as a string parameter to the `thumbHover` function. Check if the parameter exists and do your thing.

```
window.onresize = function () {
    thumbHover("absolute");
    if ($(".thumb").css("margin-bottom") === "1px") {
        $('.info-top').appendTo('#Grid');
    } else {
        $('.info-top').appendTo('#middle');
    }
};

 function thumbHover(positionVal) {
     if (positionVal.length) {
         $('.info-top').css({
             position: positionVal
         });
     }
     $('.thumb').hover(function () {
             $('.info-top').text('Hover Text');
         },
         function () {
             if (!$('.info-top').hasClass('active')) {
                 $('.info-top').text('');
             }
         });
 }
```

Comment: I would parameterize this further, and also pass in the node reference, that way it ban be re-used:
thumbHover(node,positionVal) {.... }
thumbHover($('.info-top'),"absolute");